# html2fpdf error: cannot modify header information

Tags: fpdf, html2pdf

I have a big project using this old library in PHP 5.4 and I'm trying to get a simple php page to generate a pdf. Looking at a known, good working php page I wrote this test page referencing html2fpdf which appears to be version 3.0 beta. I believe this is the last version standing. It still works in production but this simple php page returns this error:

```
Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /media/psf/Home/apps/clean/fpdf.php on line 1805

Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /media/psf/Home/apps/clean/fpdf.php on line 1828

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /media/psf/Home/apps/clean/fpdf.php:1805) in /media/psf/Home/apps/clean/fpdf.php on line 1678
FPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file
```

OK, reading about set_magic_quotes on stack tells me to upgrade the library which isn't possible that I can see. Looking at line 1805 the function is already set to false.

I'm sure it's being ignored in production but it apparently is stopping my pdf generation because it's attempting to send headers. I don't see why it would in the library.

The following test is run in apache 2.4 under php 5.4.33 and 5.6.8 with the same result.

What am I not seeing?

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 'html2fpdf.php');
// header("Content-type:application/pdf");
ob_end_clean();
ob_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>    
<form action="review_template2.php" method="post" name="MainForm">
<p>This is the review_template.tpl.php</p>
</form>    
</body>
</html>    
<?php
$filename = 'saam.pdf';
$html=ob_get_contents();    
$pdf = new HTML2FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output($filename, "D");
```

A blank pdf appears when the php header is set, but the above error when I have it commented out.
thx, sam

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `error_reporting(0);` right after `<?php`. This would disable showing the Deprecated-error messages and allows your script to modify the headers and show the PDF.
But note, that this would disable all error reporting, so you wouldn't get notified if you have another error in the script.
Alternatively you could use `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);` to just show errors which have influence on the script.
Or see the documentation on [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).